# Splitting a deferred IEnumerable<T> into two sequences without re-evaluation?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iterator, ienumerable

I have a method that needs to process an incoming sequence of commands and split the results into different buckets depending on some properties of the result.  For example:

```
class Pets
{
    public IEnumerable<Cat> Cats { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Dog> Dogs { get; set; }
}

Pets GetPets(IEnumerable<PetRequest> requests) { ... }
```

The underlying model is perfectly capable of handling the entire sequence of `PetRequest` elements at once, and also the `PetRequest` is mostly generic information like an ID, so it makes no sense to try to split the requests at the input.  But the provider doesn't actually give back `Cat` and `Dog` instances, just a generic data structure:

```
class PetProvider
{
    IEnumerable<PetData> GetPets(IEnumerable<PetRequest> requests)
    {
        return HandleAllRequests(requests);
    }
}
```

I've named the response type `PetData` instead of `Pet` to clearly indicate that it is **not** a superclass of `Cat` or `Dog` - in other words, conversion to `Cat` or `Dog` is a mapping process.  The other thing to keep in mind is that `HandleAllRequests` is expensive, e.g. a database query, so I really don't want to repeat it, **and** I would prefer to avoid caching the results in memory using `ToArray()` or the like, because there might be thousands or millions of results (I have a *lot* of pets).

So far I've been able to throw together this clumsy hack:

```
Pets GetPets(IEnumerable<PetRequest> requests)
{
    var data = petProvider.GetPets(requests);
    var dataGroups = 
        from d in data
        group d by d.Sound into g
        select new { Sound = g.Key, PetData = g };
    IEnumerable<Cat> cats = null;
    IEnumerable<Dog> dogs = null;
    foreach (var g in dataGroups)
        if (g.Sound == "Bark")
            dogs = g.PetData.Select(d => ConvertDog(d));
        else if (g.Sound == "Meow")
            cats = g.PetData.Select(d => ConvertCat(d));
    return new Pets { Cats = cats, Dogs = dogs };
}
```

This technically works, in the sense that it doesn't cause the `PetData` results to be enumerated twice, but it has two major problems:

1. It looks like a giant pimple on the code; it smacks of the awful imperative style we always used to have to employ in the pre-LINQ framework 2.0.
2. It ends up being a thoroughly pointless exercise, because the `GroupBy` method is just caching all those results in memory, which means I'm really no better off than if I'd just been lazy and done a `ToList()` in the first place and attached a few predicates.

So to restate the question:

**Is it possible to split a single deferred `IEnumerable<T>` instance into two `IEnumerable<?>` instances, *without* performing any eager evaluations, caching results in memory, or having to re-evaluate the original `IEnumerable<T>` a second time?**

Basically, this would be the reverse of a `Concat` operation.  The fact that there isn't already one in the .NET framework is a strong indication that this may not even be possible, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask anyway.

*P.S. Please don't tell me to create a `Pet` superclass and just return an `IEnumerable<Pet>`.  I used `Cat` and `Dog` as fun examples, but in reality the result types are more like `Item` and `Error` - they are both derived from the same generic data but otherwise have nothing in common at all.*

Comment: It sounds like you want to split a deffered sequence into *two deferred sequences*. Is that correct?

Comment: @Gabe: Yes, the output sequences have to also be deferred (otherwise they would be cached/eagerly loaded).

Comment: Is it possible to query the data source separately for cats and dogs? You say there might be thousands or millions of results - that raises a red flag in my mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fundamentally, no. Imagine if it *were* possible. Then consider what happens if I do:

```
foreach (Cat cat in pets.Cats)
{
    ...
}

foreach (Dog dog in pets.Dogs)
{
    ...
}
```

That needs to handle all the cats first, and then all the dogs... so what could happen with the original sequence if the first element is a `Dog`? It *either* has to cache it or skip it - it can't return it, because we're still asking for `Cats`.

You *could* implement something which only caches as much as it needs to, but that's *likely* to be the whole of one sequence, as typical usage is to completely evaluate one sequence or the other.

If at all possible, you really just want to handle pets (whether cats or dogs) as you fetch them. Would it be feasible to provide an `Action<Cat>` and an `Action<Pet>` and execute the right handler for each item?

Comment: Interesting bit in the last paragraph about `Action<T>` parameters. I've tried to keep trivial details out of the question but the real-world equivalent of the `Pets` class is actually ultimately destined for serialization.  In theory I guess it could do that (i.e. write the data directly to a file / socket) - unfortunately that would probably involve more re-architecting than I have time for.

Comment: @Aaronaught: How about a `Func<Cat, byte[]>` etc? In other words, "give me the serialized form of the cat"? Basically you want to hook in so you can process all the values as you fetch them.

Comment: Yes, that's true... but here are the nit-picky details kicking in, serializing the entities out of order would break the schema, because it expects all the `Dogs` to come after all the `Cats` (so to speak).  Still, a good suggestion for the general case.

Comment: @Aaronaught: Ah - if all the dogs have to come before all the cats, then you have *no choice* - there's got to be some caching somewhere. Now that could be the serialized form - serialize dogs to the "real" stream, cats to a MemoryStream, and then copy the MemoryStream to the real stream when you reach the end of the pets. Fundamentally, consider what you can do if you read a cat first - you either handle it, forget it, or cache it. There aren't any other options :)

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think the "cache as needed" strategy might actually work in this scenario. In the majority of cases, *most* of the results will be in the first bucket (`Cat`), so I can try to finagle a system that spools the "special" results (`Dog`) and iterates the "normal" results.

Comment: @Aaronaught: +1 for 'finagle'

Answer (score 2):

What [Jon said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346937/splitting-a-deferred-ienumerablet-into-two-sequences-without-re-evaluation/6347003#6347003) (I'm sure I'm the 1 millionth person to say that).

I'd probably just go old-school and do:

```
List<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>();
List<Dog> dog = new List<Dog>();

foreach(var pet in data)
{
   if (g.Sound == "Bark")
     dogs.Add(ConvertDog(pet));
   else if (pet.Sound == "Meow")
     cats.Add(ConvertCat(pet));
}
```

But I realise this is not exactly what you want to do - but then you did say *re*-evaluation - and this does only evaluate once :)

Comment: It is in fact exactly what I *don't* want to do: Caching the data in memory.  Since the transform is multiplicative (size-wise), it would end up being more efficient to eagerly load the entire input sequence and return two `Where` enumerables based on it.

Comment: @Aaronaught - would Rx help? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609 - then instead of using `List<T>` you can immediately pull the objects through the enumerables and then dump them when done.

Comment: It might - it's one of the options I was considering - but so far I haven't been able to come up with any approaching a concrete solution, just a similarly vague idea.

Comment: @Aaronaught, yes, well I must confess I haven't yet found a reason to justify using or even experimenting properly with Rx yet, despite its obvious coolness, so I can't suggest how to use it! Equally trying to use it conjunction with your need to order the results would, I think, provide an 'interesting' challenge :)